# Postgresql como extraer datos de un JSON que esta dentro de otro JSON

Tags: json, postgresql

Soy nueva con JSON no se como sacar un dato, tengo una tabla **DOCUMENTOS**, la cual ademas de otros campos, tiene uno que es *Props*, dentro de este hay JSON, el cual tiene varios datos, uno de ellos es becas, el cual tiene embebido otro JSON.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito sacar del campo *Props* la parte de becas solamente el **tipo**
La consulta que corro es la siguiente:

```
select  doc.props::json->>'areaTematicaPrincipalCode' as "AT",
doc.props::json->>'becas' as becas
from proyectos p
left join documentos doc on doc.uidref = p.uid AND tiporef = 'PROYECTO'
where p.nombre like 'PC-2020%' and p.estado = 'VI'  --ENVIAD
```

Me muestra lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A mi solo me interesa tener AT  y el tipo, el resto no. Si me pueden ayudar o darme una idea les agradecería

Comment: pon el objeto como código por favor, mira que si lo pones como imagen nos dificulta sobremanera probar una solución tentativa

Answer (score 0):

Dado un objeto de un solo nivel de profundidad, representado, por ejemplo, por

```
  { 
    perro: 'bobby',
    gato: 'kitty'
  }
```

Si tu propósito pudiese expresarse como

> - dado el objeto, quiero obtener el valor de la propiedad 'gato'

Para todo lenguaje de programación que soporte objetos, la lógica es más o menos la misma, aunque cada uno use operadores distintos:

```
   objeto.gato  // javascript
   $objeto->gato // PHP
   objeto::json->>'gato' // PostgreSQL
```

(El casteo explícito a tipo json se hace porque PostgreSQL es quisquilloso con los tipos de dato, y el doble chevron para obtener el valor sin comillas)

Cuando el objeto tiene dos niveles de profundidad

```
  { 
    perro: 'bobby',
    gato: {
      color:'gris'
    }
  }
```

Y tu intención fuera

> - dado el objeto, quiero obtener el valor de la propiedad 'gato'
>
>   - de ésta, quiero obtener el valor de la propiedad 'color'

Todos los lenguajes son consistentes en que ello se hace operando en forma consecutiva sobre los niveles desde el más externo hacia el más interno

```
   objeto.gato.color  // javascript
   $objeto->gato->color // PHP
   (objeto::json->>'gato')::json->>'color' // PostgreSQL
```

Puede que parezca irrelevante aludir a varios lenguajes, pero sirve para visualizar qué es lo que estamos haciendo, sin importar las diferencias de implementación que cada lenguaje adopte.

---

En tu caso, reduciendo el json a lo medular, tienes algo como:

```
{ 
   "areaTematicaPrincipalCode" : "AT", 
   "becas" : [
       { "tipo" : "DOCTORAL" }
    ]
}
```

Tú necesitas solamente el tipo de beca, pero el contenido indica que `becas` es un array. Lo único distinto es que los arrays se acceden con el operador `->N` en vez de `->>'propiedad'`,  donde N es el índice numérico dentro del array. Entonces

#### Solución 1

Para el enunciado:

> - Dado el objeto, necesito el valor la beca
>
>   - de la beca, el valor de su primer elemento
>
>     - del elemento, el valor de la propiedad 'tipo'

Se usaría

```
SELECT 
    props::json->>'areaTematicaPrincipalCode' as area,
    (((props::json->>'becas')::json->0)::json)->>'tipo' as tipo
 FROM documentos
```

#### Solución 2

El supuesto de que hay sólo un elemento dentro del array es una solución particular. Si lo estructuraron como un array, esto más bien sugiere que podrían haber uno o más tipos de beca para cada área temática.

```
{ 
   "areaTematicaPrincipalCode" : "AT", 
   "becas" : [
       { "tipo" : "DOCTORAL" },
       { "tipo" : "MAGISTER" }
    ]
}
```

Podemos redefinir el enunciado como:

> - Dado el objeto, necesito el valor de la propiedad 'beca'
>
>   - de la beca, el valor **de cada uno de sus elementos**
>
>     - de cada elemento, el valor de su propiedad 'tipo'

PG ofrece muchas funciones para convertir JSON a recordsets, JSON a JSON[], JSON a ARRAY, etc etc. Para no confundirte más, lo siguiente entregaría tantas filas como tipos de becas haya en el array, y en cada uno la propiedad 'area' se repetirá consistentemente

```
SELECT 
    props::json->>'areaTematicaPrincipalCode' as area,
    json_array_elements((props::json->>'becas')::json)::json->>'tipo' as tipo
FROM documentos
```

Nótese que esta última solución te funcionará también para el caso en que haya un solo tipo de beca.

#### Solución 3

¿Qué pasa si el array también pudiese venir vacío, porque no hay becas en esa área?

Antes de abordar ese caso, digamos que este es el contenido de la tabla (en realidad de su campo json)

| props |
| --- |
| {"areaTematicaPrincipalCode":"AT","becas":[{"tipo":"DOCTORAL"},{"tipo":"MAGISTER"}]} |
| {"areaTematicaPrincipalCode":"JK","becas":[]} |
| {"areaTematicaPrincipalCode":"XR","becas":[{"tipo":"POSTGRADO"}]} |

La solución 1 mostraría el primer elemento de cada registro, incluyendo el del área JK que es nulo:

| area | tipo |
| --- | --- |
| AT | DOCTORAL |
| JK | null |
| XR | POSTGRADO |

La solución 2 mostraría los dos tipos de beca ofrecidas en el área AT, pero omitiría el registro JK, ya que  `json_array_elements` no
tiene becas para iterar.

| area | tipo |
| --- | --- |
| AT | DOCTORAL |
| AT | MAGISTER |
| XR | POSTGRADO |

Así que -si fuese necesario listar el área "JK" aunque no tenga becas,  podríamos comprobar el largo del array. Si no tiene contenido, diremos en cambio que tiene un único elemento, de valor `null`.

```
SELECT 
  props::json->>'areaTematicaPrincipalCode' as area,
  json_array_elements(CASE
   WHEN json_array_length((props::json->>'becas')::json)=0 THEN '[null]'::json
   ELSE (props::json->>'becas')::json
  END)->>'tipo' as tipo
FROM documentos;
```

Y esto nos da

| area | tipo |
| --- | --- |
| AT | DOCTORAL |
| AT | MAGISTER |
| JK | null |
| XR | POSTGRADO |

Te dejo un fiddle de ejemplo: https://dbfiddle.uk/szIR7CGI